# Problema al dejar carrito vacío

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo hecho un carrito de compras funcionando, cuando lo vacío me lanza este error que necesito corregir, a ver si sabéis decirme/orientarme por donde corregir. El error es:

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\davecorium\includes\funciones.php:42 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\davecorium\includes\funciones.php(42): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'SELECT strNombr...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\davecorium\tienda\basketresume.php(174): SacarNombreProducto(NULL) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\davecorium\includes\funciones.php on line 42*

Uso Dreamweaver por lo que si hay errores de sintaxis me avisa, aún así, busqué algún **);** y comillas **''** o **""** pero no arreglé nada.

Este es el código `php` con la función `SacarNombreProducto`:

```
function SacarNombreProducto($identificador)
{
global $link, $database_db;
mysqli_select_db($link, $database_db);
$query_SacarProducto = sprintf("SELECT strNombre FROM tabla_productos WHERE idProductos = $identificador");
$SacarProducto = mysqli_query($link, $query_SacarProducto) or die(mysqli_error());
$row_SacarProducto = mysqli_fetch_assoc($SacarProducto);
$totalRows_SacarProducto = mysqli_num_rows($SacarProducto);
return   $row_SacarProducto['strNombre']; 
mysqli_free_result($SacarProducto);

}
```

La página `php` que gestiona la actualización de productos es `basketresume.php` y este es el código de la sesión

```
$varUsuario_Basket_carrito = "0";
if (isset($_SESSION["loggedin"])) {
  $varUsuario_Basket_carrito = $_SESSION["loggedin"];
}
mysqli_select_db($link, $database_db);
$query_Basket_carrito = sprintf("SELECT * FROM tblbasket WHERE tblbasket.idUsuario = %s AND tblbasket.intTransacciones = 0", GetSQLValueString($link, $varUsuario_Basket_carrito, "int"));
$Basket_carrito = mysqli_query($link, $query_Basket_carrito) or die(mysqli_error());
$row_Basket_carrito = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Basket_carrito);
$totalRows_Basket_carrito = mysqli_num_rows($Basket_carrito);
```

Y después tras más código para paypal (que omito mostrar) está este otro dónde se usa la función `SacarNombreProducto`

```
$i = (int)0;
  do { 
     $i++;

      $_nombre____TT = SacarNombreProducto ($row_Basket_carrito['idProducto']);
      $_precio = (float)$row_Basket_carrito['dblPrecio'];
      $_cantidad =(int) $row_Basket_carrito['intCantidad'];
      $totalLinea = (float) $_precio * $_cantidad;

        $textoPaypal  .= "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"item_name_" . $i . "\" value=\"" . $_nombre____TT .  "\">";
        $textoPaypal  .= "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"amount_"    . $i . "\" value=\"" . $_precio .  "\">";
        $textoPaypal  .= "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"quantity_"  . $i . "\" value=\"" . $_cantidad . "\">";?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo SacarNombreProducto($row_Basket_carrito['idProducto'])  ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $_cantidad; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $_precio; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $totalLinea;?></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
    $_preciototal += $totalLinea;
    } while ($row_Basket_carrito = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Basket_carrito)); ?>

<tr bgcolor="#F3EDD8">
  <td align="right" class="big_link">&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="big_link">Total</td>
  <td class="big_link"><?php echo $_preciototal;?>€</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

He probado colocando la conexión delante

```
$_nombre____TT = SacarNombreProducto ($link, $row_Basket_carrito['idProducto']);
```

pero me arroja otro error, este:

> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string*

Libero las consultas con

```
<?php mysqli_free_result();?>
```

Resumo, el carrito funciona, añado productos, sumo, elimino de uno en uno, toda la fila, etc. Este aviso de error sale cuando lo vacío o dejo a cero.
¿Veis la solución?, busque aquí y no vi nada, ni en la web.
Saludos!

Nueva edición: Seguí los consejos de Matias P y funciona, voto a favor. así quedó el código:

```
$_nombre____TT = 'idProducto';
$_precio = 'dblPrecio';
$_cantidad = 'intCantidad';


$i = (int)0;
while ($row_Basket_carrito = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Basket_carrito)){
$i++;

$_nombre____TT = SacarNombreProducto ($row_Basket_carrito['idProducto']);
$_precio = (float)$row_Basket_carrito['dblPrecio'];
$_cantidad =(int) $row_Basket_carrito['intCantidad'];
$totalLinea = (float) $_precio * $_cantidad;

$textoPaypal  .= "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"item_name_" . $i . "\" value=\"" . $_nombre____TT .  "\">";
$textoPaypal  .= "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"amount_"    . $i . "\" value=\"" . $_precio .  "\">";
$textoPaypal  .= "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"quantity_"  . $i . "\" value=\"" . $_cantidad . "\">";

?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo SacarNombreProducto($row_Basket_carrito['idProducto'])  ?></td>
<td><?php echo $_cantidad; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $_precio; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $totalLinea;?></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<?php 
$_preciototal += $totalLinea;
}
?>          
<tr bgcolor="#F3EDD8">
<td align="right" class="big_link">&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td class="big_link">Total</td>
<td class="big_link"><?php echo $_preciototal;?>€</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te está mencionando que le estás pasando `NULL` a `SacarNombreProducto()`por lo que deberías hacer while - do en vez de do - while, porque el do while se ejecuta al menos una vez y aún no tienes la información:

```
do { 
  // Acceder en este punto a $row_Basket_carrito NO está definido
} while ($row_Basket_carrito = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Basket_carrito));
```

```
while ($row_Basket_carrito = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Basket_carrito)) { 
  // Acceder en este punto $row_Basket_carrito SI está definido
}
```

Haciendo este cambio te debería funcionar, pero tienes que incializar las variables antes de usarlas dentro del while.

Comment: Funcionó, perfecto.